# Facebook SDK Initialization for SDK v3.23.1 to implement App Events for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I am trying to follow the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android#legacy-activation in the section "Legacy SDK Initialization". They say that "in the Facebook SDK for Android v4.18, and earlier, the SDK must be initialized". I am using Facebook SDK v3.23.1. They provide a code to demonstrate how to initialize the SDK. The problem that I am experiencing is that as part of the sample code, they use the following two lines:

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

When I try to do that, I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'FacebookSdk'
```

By testing, I realized that `import com.facebook.FacebookSdk` can only be used from Facebook SDK 4.0.0 and higher, but I am using Facebook SDK 3.23.1. Is there an alternative way to initialize Facebook SDK for SDK v3.23.1?

Comment: I am reading the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookSdk/, but I do not see information about the Facebook SDK versions that support the FacebookSdk class. I guess Facebook SDK 3.23.1 does not support it, but is there an equivalent function? Otherwise, how am I supposed to initialize Facebook SDK in order to implement App Events using SDK version 3.23.1?

Comment: Confirmed. The FacebookSdk class does not even exist in Facebook SDK 3.23.1: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23/. How am I supposed to initialize the SDK and implement App Events for Android in this case?

Comment: No need to initialize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using the AppEventsLogger class by following the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23.1/class/AppEventsLogger/. I did not have to initialize Facebook SDK v3.23.1, and I guess it is not even possible to initialize it because they do not provide a method to do that in the SDK 3.23.1 release.